# Fixing CSS in lightning community

Tags: css, lightning-design-system, lightning-community

I'm trying to fix css for the lightning community, I have created a custom theme for a community, and my component implements `forceCommunity:layout`, due to `forceCommunity:layout` by default `max-width` is set to 1440px;
I tried to override this it but as it's a parent element so I'm not able to override it. Please check below image

[image]

I tried following css but all elements are misplaced now

```
    left: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
```

Now elements are fit in the screen but all elements are overlapped on each other, need some help here, thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to resolve?

Comment: I'm working on it..I'll update it once done..sorry for delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a custom Theme layout if you want to expand/change the width of your page, since the content layout is embedded within the content area of the custom theme layout component.

[Create Custom Theme Layout Components for Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm)

your theme layout would then be set in the mainContentArea below:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:themeLayout" access="global" description="Sample Custom Theme Layout">
    <aura:attribute name="search" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="profileMenu" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="navBar" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="newHeader" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <div class="themed-page">
        <div class="searchRegion">
            {!v.search}
        </div>
        <div class="profileMenuRegion">
            {!v.profileMenu}
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
            {!v.navBar}
        </div>
        <div class="newHeader">
            {!v.newHeader}
        </div>
        <div class="mainContentArea">
            {!v.body}
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Style.css

```
.THIS .themed-page{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help @glls, that worked for me, now all required div sections are stretched to fit